# Where to store user data persistently across app updates (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app that contains a local database. I would like to give the user the possibility to bookmark some items in this database, and that these bookmarks do not disappear every time the app (and thus the database) is updated. What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: A user's data of your app is persisted during regular app update, so you can store it anywhere in container. (If of course by update you don't mean remove/re-install).

Comment: Use document or library app directories , not cache or temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest method of persisting data across app restarts is by using UserDefaults. In your case you can store custom data types in a UserDefaults key as follows:

1. Init defaults object

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

2. Create a custom data type for your data (needs to be Codable)

```
struct Bookmark: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Bookmarks: Codable {
    let bookmarks: [Bookmark]
}
```

3. Save data as follows

```
// data is of type Bookmarks here
if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data) {
    defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "bookmarks")
}
```

4. Retrieve data later

```
if let savedData = defaults.object(forKey: "bookmarks") as? Data {
    if let savedBookmarks = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Bookmarks.self, from: savedData) {
        print("Saved user: \(savedBookmarks)")
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-use-userdefaults-in-swift/) and [here](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-use-userdefaults-in-swiftui/)